# IsolatedStorage Window Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two filed `Name` and `Image` on my page. I want to save these two thing in database and also view all saved data.

I used `PhotoChooserTask` to choose image and saved that image in isolated storage and also save image path in database using follwoing code.

```
CategoryVO newCategory = new CategoryVO()
{
    Name = txtCategoryName.Text,
    ImagePath = txtCategoryName.Text.Trim() + ".jpg"
};
Expdb.Category.InsertOnSubmit(newCategory);
Expdb.SubmitChanges();
```

I dont know how to save image path in databse table means what is the path of image which I saved in isolated storage and how to bind images into datagrid from those path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of file you saved in isolated storage  isostore:/your file name

It depends on, in which folder you saved your image. If you save file directly without creating folder, then isostore:/your file name is enough to refer to your image file.

[IsoStore Example](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/new-uri-schemes-windows-phone)